# How to resize rows in a datagridview so that they fill the entire control and all have the same height

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am currently working at an events management application.

So far I have used a `DataGridView` control to display a monthly calendar:

[image]

But the table rows are not properly sized.

I would like to achieve something like in the photo below:

[image]

Notice that the heights of the six rows are the same and the proportion is maintained if the grid is resized.

I tried to achieve that with `DataGridView.AutoResizeRows`. It didn't work.
Is there a solution?

Comment: @TaW It seems you posted your comment before my answer, when I was writing code :) I removed my answer. Feel free to post your answer, you have my vote :)

Comment: @Reza: No, do undelete it; it is more complete and stands on its own..!

Comment: @TaW Thank you for your kindness. I undeleted the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`ScrollBars`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.scrollbars?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `DataGridView` to `None` and use this code to set size of rows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Height = (dataGridView1.ClientRectangle.Height - dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight) / dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
}
```

Also use this code to handle resizing:

```
private void dataGridView1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Height = (dataGridView1.ClientRectangle.Height - dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight) / dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but on the condition that AutoSizeRowsMode has the value None.

Comment: You are welcome :) The default value of `AutoSizeRowsMode`  is `None` so I didn't mentioned it.