# Can DataGridView be used to accomplish the following table-like UI in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

It's been a pain in the butt, but I've been using a `TableLayoutPanel` to display some data as seen in the below screenshot. But several times it's been suggested that this can be *easily done* with a `DataGridView`.

So my question is, can the following screenshot be accomplished in a Windows Form using a `DataGridView`? I've searched the web and nothing similar to what's below.

An answer would be **"Yes, it can."** or **"No, it's not possible."**. But please do not post alternatives since the purpose of the question is to finally know if something like this can be accomplished a `DataGridView`.

The `DataTable` looks like the following:

```
BG_Color    EmpId     ColNum    RowNum
Yellow      4304      1         1
Yellow      8464      2         1
Yellow      2012      3         1
Blue        4593      1         2
Blue        3515      2         2
Blue        0546      3         2
Green       4346      1         3
Green       5426      2         3
Green       0551      3         3
```

The result is the following. It's display-only and nothing's clickable here:

[image]

How is this possible with a `DataGridView`? I've even included where exactly each cell will be, by `RowNum` and `ColNum`, just in case it's needed.

Or if someone can share a link on something similar, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, BUT.... you need to use your own format like rowHeight, backColor, etc...

Comment: The rowheight's arbitrary; it can be any height. The backcolor's in the datatable.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759540/displaying-a-collection-of-controls-in-windows-forms/32759588#32759588) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753433/how-to-resize-rows-in-a-datagridview-so-that-they-fill-the-entire-control-and-al/34753729#34753729).

Comment: @MaciejLos, the question was not how to bind data to a `DataGridView`. Will your link accomplish what you see in the screenshot?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But do tell us: With or without data binding? Also: Are the colors stored as strings and if so are they taken from KnownColors names?

Comment: @TaW, considering that the datatable changes frequently, I prefer data binding. Also, the colors are stored as string and they're taken from KnownColors names. For background, I can use `Control.BackColor = Color.FromName(color);`. where `color` is a string.

Comment: You can not do it using data-binding because of the structure of data. Instead, you can simply use cell formatting.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, it's partially true only. It's possible to bind data to datatable, but it needs to define custom method to change row background color when datatable is binded.

Comment: @MaciejLos No, it's completely true. Look at row count of sample data.  It has 9 rows. If you need databinding the data structure should be change.

Comment: It's called a Beauty of programming ;) [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85kxk29c(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Why in the world would you use a DataGridView for this? It would be far easier to use Panels or UserControls inside of a TableLayoutPanel. Where is the "pain in the butt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create such user interface using a `DataGridView`:

- You can set `RowCount` and `ColumnCount` of grid manually.
- You can hanlde `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` and set the value and back color of cell there.
- You can not use data-binding with current structure of data.

Here is a working example with your sample data:

```
DataTable table;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table = GetData();
    this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
    this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 64;
    this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = (int)table.Compute("Max(ColNum)", "");
    this.dataGridView1.RowCount = (int)table.Compute("Max(RowNum)", "");
}
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 & e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        var row = table.Select(string.Format("RowNum={0} AND ColNum={1}",
            e.RowIndex + 1, e.ColumnIndex + 1)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (row != null)
        {
            e.Value = row["EmpId"];
            var color = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom(row["BG_Color"]);
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = color;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = color;
            e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;
            e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer to use `TableLayoutPanel` for such amount of data and such UI. The post just tries to answer your question *Can datagridview be used to accomplish the following in winform?*

Comment: It seems `TableLayoutPanel` is indeed the better choice. I asked because every time I post something about the `TableLayoutPanel`, someone always comments on how easily it would be with a `DataGridView`. And judging by this code and the link someone else posted, it's far from easy.

Comment: Yes, for this case `TableLayoutPanel` is better option.

Comment: I was looking at your code for the datagridview, and with the example data, it looks pretty good. Would your answer require both ColNum and RowNum in the datatable to work? The total number of rows would always be the same (3), and I can include the ColNum.

Comment: Using `(int)table.Compute("Max(ColNum)", "");` makes column numbers dynamic, the same with row number. If you know for column count is for exmaple 3, you can use 3 instead. But I prefer to keep using `Max`.

Comment: But you do `DataTable.Select` with `RowNum`, and I don't have `RowNum`. Assuming the `DataTable` doesn't have field `RowNum`, would your code work?

Comment: Your datatable in example have a column named `RowNum`. I can't get what you mean.

Comment: I added it for the purposes of the example. But would it all be possible if field `RowNum` didn't exist?

Comment: If not, I can add the rownum into the datatable. No worries.

Comment: Yes, surely it will be possible. You don't need to add it to database. At least you can add it to query using `row_number`.

Comment: A different data structure needs a different calculation to extract cell value and cell color. For example, you can find the row of data table by its index. In the event use `var index = e.RowIndex * this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount + e.ColumnIndex;`  then `var row = table.Rows[index];` something like that. I didn't test it but it should be something like that.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, it's quite easy to achieve that, but there's only one condition: the data stored in the datatable have to be pivoted. How? Take a look at example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //create DataTable
        DataTable dt = CreateCustomDataTable();
        var pivotDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("RowNum"))
        .Select(grp => new
        {
            BG_Color = grp.First().Field<string>("BG_Color").ToLower(), //System.Drawing.Color.FromName(grp.First().Field<string>("BG_Color")),
            Emp1 = grp.Where(e => e.Field<int>("ColNum") == 1).Select(a => a.Field<int>("EmpId")).SingleOrDefault(),
            Emp2 = grp.Where(e => e.Field<int>("ColNum") == 2).Select(a => a.Field<int>("EmpId")).SingleOrDefault(),
            Emp3 = grp.Where(e => e.Field<int>("ColNum") == 3).Select(a => a.Field<int>("EmpId")).SingleOrDefault()
        }).ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = pivotDt;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromName(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
//...
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

For such amount of data the risk of loss of performance is equal to zero.

And ***final note*** about your main question:

> (...) can the following screenshot be accomplished in a Windows Form using a datagridview?
>
> An answer would be Yes, it can or No, it's not possible.  (...)

**Yes. it is possible - quite easily.**

Comment: I understand that it's possible, but most of the work would go into trying to fit the data into the datagridview. For example, from what I see, it seems that I need to know beforehand how many columns there are. What happens if there are 4 columns instead of 3? Is there a way to add a column dynamically?

Comment: Well... There's a way to add columns dynamically, but it would be bit harder... Are you interesting in dynamic version?

Comment: If possible, yes. I will always know how many rows there will be, but the columns are dynamic. Thanks again.

Comment: @MaciejLos Probably the answer has somethings new for learning for OP, for example using a Linq query against data table. It confirms what I said *it can not be done using databinding without changing data structure*.  - You should recreate the pivot after each load of data. - You should make your pivot support dynamic columns. - Also you are using the same `CellFormatting` event. So what's the benefit of such databinding? Btw, Good luck to your national team with the match ;)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. Don't get me wrong... I agree with you, but disagree with opinion that that isn't possible to achive using databinding, even if `CellFormattig` event have to be used. I hope you've got my point of view. Thank you for your wishes. :D BTW: +1 for your solution.

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes, I get what you mean, it seems we are saying the same thing with different sentences. +1 :)