# Does DataGridView CellFormatting execute whenever Form & Dgv have focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I assume `DataGridView.CellFormatting` executes any time the `Form` has focus, because whenever I switch from VS2010 to the actual Form, execution stops again at the breakpoint within that `event handler`. Is this correct?

If so, is there a way to avoid this? Maybe I can add a condition within the event handler?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you'll end up with the logic costing more than just letting the code execute in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)  event is designed to occur when the contents of a cell need to be formatted for display. In fact the event occurs every time each cell is painted.

You use this event to provide additional formatting like converting the value of cell to more readable or friendly text, or provide cell formatting like color or back color dynamically.

Just put a reasonable processing of value in the event handler and avoid time-consuming tasks in the event.

For more information read remarks section of [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) documentation.

Comment: I assumed as much. If you recall [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127389/can-datagridview-be-used-to-accomplish-the-following-in-winform?noredirect=1#comment63708136_38127389), the purpose was to update the DGV anytime the underlying datatable changes.

Comment: CellFormatting adds the datarows to the `DGV`, but it seems there's no way to raise this event when the `datatable` changes.

Comment: I don't have access to VS currently. But I guess calling invalidate or refresh method of grid raises the event. By the way, you don't add rows here you provide formatted value.

Comment: @rbhatup Btw, it would be great if you vote for an answer when you mark it as accepted. It's reasonable and [recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Of course. I didn't know you could accept and also upvote.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: It's common to upvote and accept for best post. Also upvote for other usefull posts. This way posts will be more useful for future readers and also it motivates users to post good answers for questions.